# Regex for ranges (and specifics) in a zero-padded string?

Tags: regex

I'm new to regex and I'm trying to match with a string that contains zero-padded digits (suffice to say I'm having some trouble).

I have a thousand files that are named as below; what I'd like to do is write a single expression that could match any file number in a range and/or specific values (like the page selection in a print dialog). So for example, files 20-30 and file 45, 50, and 55.

File naming convention = `"FILE-00001.csv" -> "FILE-01000.csv"`

To be even more annoying, there could be any number of leading zero characters. Any one have any ideas or hints that could point me in the right direction?

Comment: Like `FILE-0*(?:\d{1,3}|1000)\.csv` which matches between 1 through 1000 with any number of leading zeros?

Comment: Is the naming convention the input or the desired result?

Comment: Trying to make a regex for a range is tricky. Trying to make one for an arbitrary range (like the page selection in a print dialog) is close to impossible, and certainly not worth your time. See https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html for a single range example.

Comment: Are you doing this under Linux/Unix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as the example you've asked for,

```
FILE-0*(?:2[0-9]|[35]0|[45]5)\.csv
```

should cover files 20-30, 45, 50 and 55

[edited to use non-capturing group]